# Using DockerOperator with CeleryExecutor in airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

at this time I use the LocalExecutor with airflow. My DAG is using docker images with the DockerOperator coming with airflow. For this the docker images must be present on the PC. If I want to use a distributed executor like CeleryExecutor or KubernetesExecutor the docker images must be present on all the machines which are part of the Celery or Kubernetes cluster?

Regards
Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Since airflow workers run tasks locally, you will require to have docker images or nay other resources available locally on the worker. You could try [this](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) link to setup local docker registry which can serve docker images and save you efforts of maintaining them manually.